# Disable buttons, depending on where Form is opened from

Tags: c#, window-management

There's probably an easy solution to this, but I can't find anything on this.I have three forms:

1. Main Menu
2. Form 1
3. Form 2

Both Main Menu and Form 1 can launch Form 2. What I want to do is:

- if Form 2 is launched from Form 1, some buttons are disabled.

However

- If Form 2 is launched from Main Menu, everything is enabled.

I know there's a simple solution somewhere, but all I can find is how to open a form, and enable/disable it's parents controls, not open a child form and disable controls before Show() or whatever is called.

Comment: Is it MDI child Form?

Comment: You should add a parameter to the constructor to inform `Form 2` whether it needs to open with controls disabled or not, then set them as appropriate when `Form 2` is opened.

Comment: You might add modes for example or add a 'Form' parameter in the consttuctor and then 'if(form is MainForm)' to check for the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property to the Form2 class like this:

```
public bool HideSomeControls
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Then, right before you show the Form2 in Form1.cs, set that property:

```
form2instance.HideSomeControls = true;
form2instance.Show(); // or ShowDialog, depending...
```

Then, add a Load event handler to Form2 like this:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HideSomeControls)
    {
        someControl.Visible = false;
        someOtherControl.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Note that, if `MainMenu` and `Form1` share a single instance of `Form2`, you'll have to set `HideSomeControls` to `false` again in `MainMenu` before you show the `Form2` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable or disable controls directly within a property in the form:

```
public bool FullControl {
    get {
        return btnNew.Enabled;
    }
    set {
        btnNew.Enabled = value;
        btnDelete.Enabled = value;
    }
}
```

You can also leave out the getter completely (yes you can have write-only properties in C#):

```
public bool FullControl {
    set {
        btnNew.Enabled = value;
        btnDelete.Enabled = value;
    }
}
```

Call the form like this

```
var frm = new Form2();
frm.FullControl = true; // or false
frm.Show();
```